# MKAnnotationView is not draggable although I think it is properly implemented?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I've tried adding a MKMapView into my new app. I created a custom MKAnnotationView -> so I can change the pin's image. Everything works until I try to drag the pin. No matter what I do, it just wont. There is only one more thing left to say; the MapView is a subview of a big tableView cell. But the panning and zooming work properly, so I don't suppose it has to do with that...

Here is my code:

**MKAnnotation**

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {


}


//MKAnnotation
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end

@implementation MyAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;


@end
```

**MKAnnotationView**

```
@interface MyAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView {

}

@end

@implementation MyAnnotationView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, 38, 43)];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"partyPin.png"];

        if (!theImage)
            return nil;
        self.image = theImage;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**The view the MapView is in - delegate methods - not including the part where I init the MKAnnotation and "addAnnotation"**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)lmapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MyAnnotationView *myAnnotationView = (myAnnotationView *)[lmapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myView"];
    if(myAnnotationView == nil) {
        myAnnotationView = [[MyAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myView"];
    }

    myAnnotationView.draggable = YES;
    myAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return myAnnotationView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```

Does anyone see what I missed?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Did you make the class that implements the didChangeDragState a MKMapViewDelegate?

Comment: Assuming you did, I'd set a breakpoint after viewForAnnotation is called to see that your annotationView actually has draggable set to YES, using the lldb debugger - if you're not familiar with it, it's a fantastic tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an annotation to be draggable, it must implement a `setCoordinate` method.  Just setting the view's `draggable` property to `YES` is not enough.

Your annotation class has defined `coordinate` as `readonly`.

Instead, define it as `readwrite` or `assign` and remove the `coordinate` method (as well as the `latitude` and `longitude` ivars and properties since you'll be able to set the coordinate directly).

Also add an `@synthesize coordinate` so you don't have to write the getter/setter manually.